# RowIndex Issue : Not able to access Second Page data

Tags: c#, .net

I am working in C#.Net Gridview Concept. I am having 5 Rows in the gridview. In the second page of the gridview am having another 5 Rows. I am having a EDIT Button in all the rows. In ROW_COMMAND event my code is

```
 int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        HiddenField lbl = (HiddenField)gvItem.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("hidPI");
        string CompChainID = lbl.Value;
```

When i go to the second page and editing the 2nd row means, i am getting the RowIndex as 6. There i am getting the error. As that page had only 5 Rows.

What should i do for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `pageIndex*5+rowindex` would do the trick.

Or, in your case, just use modulus function:

```
var newRowIndex= rowIndex % 5;
```

rowindex 6 will be: `6 % 5= 1`

Comment: Where should i give this..I am getting the rowindex as 6, in the second page its searching for 6th row..But there are only 5 rows..

Comment: 6 % 5 = 1 (I cant able to understand this..Whether this is subtraction...)